# Invisible box when implementing zoom on UIScrollView (iPad)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

Firstly, I only have the graph view that display some nodes (a drag-able image).

Then, I want this graph to be able to zoom in/out.
In order to do so, I added the `UIScrollView` (Black box in the picture below) and add the graph view as a subview (Red box in the picture below).

The zoom functionality is working fine, but the thing is that there seems to be an invisible box (Red box in the 2nd picture below) that not allow my node to be dragged over this boundary.

**Is there anyway to get rid of this invisible boundary ?**

[image: Example]

Comment: Are you trying to move the graph out of its container view? It could be a clipsToBounds (property) issue. Try setting this property to NO on your view and see what happens.

Comment: @Luke Thank you for your answer, but it seems doesn't work.